# Android App Icon on Home Screen using LauncherShortcuts

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to place my app icon/shortcut on the Android home screen when the user opens the home screen. I've added this Activity to my app:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html

What should I do next?

Comment: Also, what if I only want the shortcut to be added when I first logged on to the app? Should I add an intent to the home activity? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an icon to start your activity on the home screen. You can just add this to that Activity's intent filter

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

Comment: I have that but it's not working. Is there nothing else I would need to do?

Comment: still doesnt work.. also, what if I want to call the launcherShortcuts activity explicitly from an existing screen?

Answer (score 0):

As the Home Screen is its own app, only the user can add app shortcuts/widgets to it. While you might be able to figure out how to do it with the default Home Screen App, you'll have difficulty doing that with all of the custom home screens done by the various manufacturers. At best you can inform the user how to do certain things on launch (and hope they follow your instructions).